# How to print in table format using format() method in JAVA?

Tags: java

I've tried searching for info on "\t", "\n", System.out.printf() and System.out.format() but could not get anything that work.

I'd like to arrange this data into a table with rows and columns.

```
public static void calc(int upper, int lower) {
    //System.out.print("row       ");
    //System.out.print("aaaa");
    for (int i = 0; lower <= upper; i++) {
        if (i > upper)
            break;
        int square = (int) Math.pow(i,2);
        int cube = (int) Math.pow(i,3);
        double sqrt = (double) Math.sqrt(i);
        System.out.println(square);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want the table to look like? How many rows? How many columns?

Comment: You may need to use spaces rather than tabs. A console is not a word processor, so tabs might change to a fixed number of spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to print output to the console in an organized format that looks like a table and understand that it is not possible to print exactly like a traditional table with row and column, at least not with simple code with String.format() or System.out.printf().

Looking into your code, what I understand is you are trying to print output that will have 4 columns, a number , it's square, it's cube and it's sqrt respectively.

But before going to that I would like to point out one mistake. From your code it looks like you want to find the sqaure, cube and sqrt of a number from range [`lower`, `upper`] and your condition for `for-loop` satisfies that but however your use of `i` is not relevant. I think you have misunderstood the use of iterative variable `i` here, the variable `i` here is unlike any other normal variable just it has different life span (exists only in the `for-loop` block) and it is changed in the last statement of the `for-loop`. Futher, I think you do not need this variable `i` to achieve your goal.

Below I share two ways to achive that goal, using a for-loop and a while-loop.

**Using for-loop:**

```
public static void calc(int upper, int lower) {
    System.out.printf("%10s | %10s | %10s | %10s\n", "Number", "Square", "Cube", "Sqrt");
    for (; lower <= upper; lower++) {
        int square = (int) Math.pow(lower,2);
        int cube = (int) Math.pow(lower,3);
        double sqrt = Math.sqrt(lower);
        System.out.printf("%10d | %10d | %10d | %10f\n", lower, square, cube, sqrt);
    }
}
```

**Using while-loop:**

```
public static void calc(int upper, int lower) {
    System.out.printf("%10s | %10s | %10s | %10s\n", "Number", "Square", "Cube", "Sqrt");
    while(lower <= upper) {
        int square = (int) Math.pow(lower,2);
        int cube = (int) Math.pow(lower,3);
        double sqrt = Math.sqrt(lower);
        System.out.printf("%10d | %10d | %10d | %10f\n", lower, square, cube, sqrt);
        lower += 1;
    }
}
```

**Output `calc(8, 4)` (for both codes above):**

```
Number |     Square |       Cube |       Sqrt

     4 |         16 |         64 |   2.000000

     5 |         25 |        125 |   2.236068

     6 |         36 |        216 |   2.449490

     7 |         49 |        343 |   2.645751

     8 |         64 |        512 |   2.828427
```

**Additional:**

If you want to change the right alignment to left alignment then you can just use `"-"` as shown below.

```
public static void calc(int upper, int lower) {
    System.out.printf("%-10s | %-10s | %-10s | %-10s\n", "Number", "Square", "Cube", "Sqrt");
    while(lower <= upper) {
        int square = (int) Math.pow(lower,2);
        int cube = (int) Math.pow(lower,3);
        double sqrt = Math.sqrt(lower);
        System.out.printf("%-10d | %-10d | %-10d | %-10f\n", lower, square, cube, sqrt);
        lower += 1;
    }
}
```

**Output `calc(8, 4)`:**

```
Number     | Square     | Cube       | Sqrt      

4          | 16         | 64         | 2.000000  

5          | 25         | 125        | 2.236068  

6          | 36         | 216        | 2.449490  

7          | 49         | 343        | 2.645751  

8          | 64         | 512        | 2.828427
```

**Note:**

- I used fixed `10 space` here since you declared your variables as `int` and `int` in `JAVA` can take upto `10 digits` maximum. Exception is sqrt which is a `double` value and since it is the last value so that will not cause an issue I think.

**Reference:**

- [Formatting Numeric Print Output (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Numbers and Strings)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)
- [Formatter (Java Platform SE 8 )](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)
- [PrintStream (Java Platform SE 8 )](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-)

Comment: hey thanks a lot this was a very informative answer. helped further my understanding ^^